# How to generate a random graph given the number of nodes and edges?

Tags: python, random, igraph

I am using python with igraph library:

```
from igraph import *
g = Graph()
g.add_vertices(4)
g.add_edges([(0,2),(1,2),(3,2)])
print g.betweenness()
```

I would like to generate a random graph with 10000 nodes and 100000 edges. The edges can be random. Please suggest a way to have random edges (using numpy.random.rand )

Answer (score 17):

Do you have to use `numpy.random.rand`? If not, just use [`Graph.Erdos_Renyi`](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Erdos_Renyi), which lets you specify the number of nodes and edges directly:

```
g = Graph.Erdos_Renyi(n=10000, m=100000)
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it with `numpy.random.rand`, generate the random array, threshold it with the probability you want, and then pass it to [`Graph.Adjacency`](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/python/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Adjacency):

```
adj = numpy.random.rand(edges, edges)
adj[adj > 0.999] = 1 # sets everything over 0.999 to 1
adj[adj <= 0.999] = 0 # sets everything below to 0
graph = Graph.Adjacency(adj)
```

This generates a directed graph, where adj[i, j] tells you whether there's an edge from i -> j. If you want an undirected one instead, use `Graph.Ajacency(adj, ADJ_UNDIRECTED)` - then there'll be an edge if either `adj[i, j] == 1` or `adj[j, i] == 1`.

This isn't guaranteed to give you exactly 100,000 edges - do you need that?

Comment: First, this is unfortunately not what he wanted. He wants a given number of edges. Second, this is a very inefficient way to generate a random G(n,p) graph if the graph is sparse.

Comment: Ooh, right you are - I missed the number of edges. I think my basic approach can still work for the number of nodes he's talking about - the adjacency matrix is wasteful (100M cells for 100k edges), but you only need it to create the graph.

Comment: `numpy.random.rand(edges, edges)` should be `numpy.random.rand(nodes, nodes)` I think